# how to add custom livechatTranscript body before chat

Tags: livechattranscript

My situation is cutomer will chat with a AI bot first, when the chat is handoff , a salesforce session would be created , then let the customer chat with the salesforce agent.
My question is how to add the chat history between customer and bot to the session before chat with agent by salesforce api, so the agent can see what the customer has chat before.